# Can you package and launch an adobe AIR application from within a native Android application?

Tags: android, actionscript, air, native

I work for a company that has a an adobe AIR game/application for Android.   We are now developing a native application for android.  We would like to reuse the game component of the AIR application and launch the AIR game from within the native application. Basically the AIR game will be one of many games in an arcade in the native application.

My question is, is this even possible?  If so what would be the best way to accomplish this.  Also is it possible for the packaged AIR application to communicate back to the native framework?  I am familiar with Native extensions but those typically wrap native or 3rd party functionality to be used with actionscript in the AIR application.  If anyone has any advice or ideas it would be much appreciated.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is possible, but if you don't mind it being two sepparate applications, they can launch each other using Intents.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html

What is comes down to is firing an intent wich the other application listens to(This is also why you can select multiple apps to open up some filetypes; they all listen to the same intent). Also if you look closely you can see that the default application code in Eclipse(at least) listens to the Launch(or something like that) intent.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  That may be a viable solution.  My question then is it possible for the android native application to check if the separate AIR application is already installed and prompt the user to download it if it is not?  For example the user clicks on one of the AIR based games within out "arcade", could the native app start a download of the game, and then launch it via an intent from that point forward.

Comment: Im not exactly sure how, but this has to be possible. Maybe you can get a list of installed application packages. If your packagename isn't in it, you open a link to the Play Store. That will ask the user to open it up in the Play Store app, or in a browser. Or use an intent directed at the playstore app, so it will always open in the Play Store app instead of asking.. Sorry for the delay, I was on vacation.